# Is there a multidimensional array type in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have programmed in [Microsoft Small Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Small_Basic) in the past, which can have arrays like this:

```
Array[1][1] = "Hello"
Array[1][2] = "Hi"
Array[1][2] = "Hey"
```

Now, in Javascript, I know how to create a single array (`var Array = New Array()`) but are there any array types like the ones above?

Comment: Array elements may be numbers, strings, objects ... or arrays. Just stack 'em up. BTW prefer `var array = [];` to `var array = new Array();`

Comment: What does "I have some small basic" mean?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Presumably "I have used a little BASIC in the past."

Comment: @cdhowie: Sure, were that valid BASIC syntax.

Comment: That is "Small Basic". A programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to create an `array` of `arrays`:

```
var x = new Array(3);
x[0] = new Array(3);
x[1] = new Array(3);
x[2] = new Array(3);

x[0][0] = "Hello";
etc.
```

Remember that indexing is zero-based.

*Edit*

Or:

```
var x=[];
x[0] = [];
x[1] = [];
x[2] = [];
...
x[0][0] = "Hello";

etc.
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it's fine if used for the behaviour of setting the length. If they were empty, `[]` would definitely be better.

Comment: @alex: It's pretty rare to need to set an array length beforehand.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do it often, generally in conjunction with `join()`.

Answer (score 8):

There are no true multidimensional arrays in JavaScript. But you can create an array of arrays like you have done.

JavaScript's arrays are just objects with a special `length` property and a different prototype chain.

Comment: Thanks! Thats all I needed to know.

Comment: "Small Basic" is a programming language.

Comment: Sorry. It needed some clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just declare an array, and initialize it with a bunch of other arrays.  For example:

```
var mArray = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6]
  ];

window.alert(mArray[1][1]); //Displays 5
```

As others have pointed out, this is not  *actually* a multi-dimentional array in the standard sense.  It's just an array that *happens* to contain other arrays.  You could just as easily have an array that had 3 other arrays, an int, a string, a function, and an object.  JavaScript is cool like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this:

```
var o = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
```

Also you can use the fact that objects in javascript are dictionaries:

```
var o;
o["0"] = {'0':1, '1':2, '1':3};
var x = o["0"]["1"]; //returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create arrays statically in JS like this:

```
var arr = [
   [1, 2, 3, 4], 
   [8, 6, 7, 8]
];
```

Note that since this is not a true "multidimentional array", just an "array of arrays" the "inner arrays" do not have to be the same length, or even the same type. Like so:

```
var arr = [
   [1, 2, 3, 4], 
   ["a", "b"]
];
```